# Add Order attribute to New Order Email

Tags: attributes, email, magento2.2.7

How do I add the value of an order attribute to the New Order Email template. Specifically an attribute called `delivery_date` stored in `sales_order_grid`.

I tried to reverse engineer how `{{var order.getShippingDescription()}}` works but with no success.

**EDIT:** I should add that another method I tried was by editing the Email Templates...

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml
```

...and adding this line to it.

```
$deliverydate = $order->getDeliveryDate()
```

(Hoping that I could grab the data the same way that I'd grab a Product Attribute). But that method also returned no value.

Comment: IS `delivery_date`  the field of sales_order table?

Comment: Yes, `delivery_date` is also in the `sales_order` table

Answer (score 0):

you should use the `email_order_set_template_vars_before` event.

write an observer for the event and add you desired data. then in the email template you have to add the data.

Comment: Please, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Craig done. it's pretty simple

Comment: Ok, I'll look into into it - Cheers